# How to use php for loop in jquery for fullcalender.js with laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalender.js to show dynamic data from php mysql with laravel framework. this is showing me only first data of table.

below is my json from mysql db.

```
[
  {
    "rp_status": "Paid",
    "emi_date": "08-09-2018",
  },
  {
    "rp_status": "UnPaid",
    "emi_date": "22-09-2018",
  },
  {
    "rp_status": "UnPaid",
    "emi_date": "06-10-2018",

  },
]
```

and below is my jquery fullcalendar code. I am using for loop for the same but it show my only first row from database.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventSources: [
    {
      events: [
       @for($i = 0; $i< count($repay_info); $i++)
        {
          title  : '{{ $repay_info[$i]["rp_status"] }}',
          start  : '{{date("d-m-Y", strtotime($repay_info[$i]["emi_date"]))}}',
          rendering: 'background',
          backgroundColor: '{{ $repay_info[$i]["rp_status"]}}', 
        },
      @endfor
      ],


        textColor: 'white'
    }

  ]

});
```

I am sharing my image of output below for reference.

[image]

Comment: you should avoid combining backend + front end javascript code whenever possible. Perhaps look into making an API end point that requests the data from the database?

Comment: It's more organized and safe if you create a route to get the events you need from the db, see here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed